# Best way to load a file (not a python module) relative to sys.path

Tags: python, import

I'd like to load a file from somewhere in the python path (`sys.path`), in a similar way as you can do in java with `Class.getResourceAsStream()`. This file is not a python module, but I happen to (ab)use python packaging for a repo that basically contains a collection of JSON files.

So, to be clear, the packaged data contains no python except for a `setup.py` file. It's an egg with no python inside.
The project that uses the packaged data is the one with python code.

I use `pip install -e <the git URL>` to install the package. It ends up in my virtual environment at `<env_path>/src/<repo>`. This location appears as one of the entries in `sys.path`.

Is there a simple-ish library call that lets me find the absolute path to one such file, without me having to search for the file by looping through `sys.path`?

Something like:

```
path = find_in_sys_path('campaigns/get.json')
```

...whatever `find_in_sys_path` should actually be called.

Comment: This is pretty easy to implement, but are you sure you want to search `sys.path` for this instead of just taking the path of the module that requires the resource? If another package contains a file with the same name, you end up loading the wrong file.

Comment: [PEP302](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) import hook ?

Comment: @larsmans I guess you mean "the module that contains the resource"?. In my case the resource is in a package that contains no python code at all, I only happen use python packaging for that. But your comment got me thinking that I know the name of the package, so I can find its entry in sys.path.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout setuptools https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#resourcemanager-api

```
import pkg_resources
my_data = pkg_resources.resource_string(__name__, "campaigns/get.json")
```

Comment: Looks interesting but I cannot use this because what I want to do is load resources that live in a totally different package. The "package" I install in my python project does not actually contain any python, only json files, so I don't have anything meaningful to pass as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

After reading @larsmans [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609152/best-way-to-load-a-file-not-a-python-module-relative-to-sys-path#comment40005411_25609152), I realised that although my egg-packaged data contains no python module that I can use as a reference to load a resource, I can easily locate its absolute path from `sys.path` with something like:

```
path = filter(lambda x: 'rbx-api-mocks' in x, sys.path)[0]
# rbx-api-mocks is the "egg name"
```

That I can later use to build the path to the resource with:

```
resource = os.path.join(path, 'campaigns', 'campaign', 'query.json')
```

I will probably end up going for that.